# Connect php application to MS SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server

TLDR: I'd like to connect a php application to a MS SQL server through an active directory account but haven't had much luck finding documentation on how to do that.

Most of the issues that people seem to have with this are pretty complicated I think I just don't have a strong enough grasp of the concept.  When I try to connect it to the server, I get:
Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The code I'm using is:

```
$user_name = "ADAccountName";
$pass_word = "ADAccountPW";
$datbase = "myDatabase";
$server = "#ipaddress#:#port#";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
```

I created a user "sa" through MS SQL Server Management Studio and attached it to an AD account (I don't seem to have access to create one without picking an AD account).

I've had luck connecting it to a database using MySQL Workbench (for testing) and a dedicated username/password, but the actual database I need to use is run by MS SQL Server Manager with an AD account.  I've spent the greater part of the day going through forums and Microsoft's documentation on SQL Server Manager but I haven't found anything that can help me out with this.

I'm using php v. 5.2

Comment: To begin with, you need to use one of PHP's MS SQL APIs, rather than `mysql_connect()` which is strictly a MySQL client.

Comment: For starters, `mysql_` functions are obsolete and insecure, and should never be used. Try PDO's extension for MSSQL: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: There's [the mssql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) but it would be better to start learning [to use PDO instead](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which supports multiple RDBMS.

Comment: @WesCossick is 100% correct.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I've played around with pdos a little in the past and will take a look at that in more detail.  Is the mysql_connect() function the reason I'm getting shut out?

Comment: @EnjielJKaldwor What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @EnjielJKaldwor Check my answer, it may help. Also, what webserver are you running apache or IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to connect to MSSQL you will need to do a few things to your web server first.

1.[You will need to add PHP to your windows startup](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath)
[image: More Info]

2.[Then you will need to install SQL Server Native client](http://www.connectionstrings.com/download-sql-server-native-client/)

3.[Install the SQL Server drivers for your web server. SQLSRV30 is for PHP 5.4, SQLSRV31 is for PHP 5.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

4.Then go to your php.ini file and enable these extensions.

[This will enable you to use PHP Data Objects.](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)

You can connect to the DB like this:

```
try
{
    $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=AdventureWorks", "sa", "");
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(Exception $e)
{ 
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
}
```

Comment: I'm still trying to get this to work.  I can't seem to get past "could not find driver1".  I looked up a few forums so far but haven't gotten a good solution.  I'm going to keep plugging away at this and see if I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Post your phpinfo() page, it will help me. You should see: Registered PHP Streams php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, phar, sqlsrv. Also if you're using an older version of PHP <5.4 you probably need SQLSRV20 drivers...

Comment: I got it to work.  I was trying to connect my application to the server from my computer using XAMPP.  I I moved the application to the server and I was able to get it to work.  I'm assuming it was an issue with connecting to an IIS server using XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

Depending which version of PHP you are using you could do the following

resource mssql_connect ([ string $servername [, string $username [, string $password [, bool $new_link = false ]]]] )

URL - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

This would give you direct connection to the DB.

Comment: That's what I have.  The server shakes it's head at my mssql_connect() the same way bouncers used to do when I thought I could sneak into the bar.  It's a little depressing but it helps me realize that I'm just going about it the wrong way.